# Vote non-functional with "thumbs_up"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to add a vote for my applivation RoR wthe the gem"Thumbs_up",but when i click in "vote_up" or "vote_down", nothing happens, i did'nt khnow the problem
my cod in viex is:

```
  = javascript_include_tag 'votecount'
        = t "idea.colaboration.accept.what_do_you_want_html", user: @collab.user.name
        .buttons[style="float:right"]
          button[type="submit"]
           = link_to image_tag('thumb_up.png'), vote_up_idea_path(@idea), data: {vote: "up"}, remote: true,:method => :post
          button[type="submit"]
           = link_to image_tag('thumb_down.png'), vote_down_idea_path(@idea), data: {vote: "down"}, remote: true,:method => :post
```

and in the "votecount.js", i have:

```
$(function(){
    $(".ratelink").click(function(){
        var val = $(this).attr('updown');
        var theid = $(this).attr('theid');
        $("#votewrapper").block({ //blocks rate-rates while processing
            message: null,
            overlayCSS: {
                backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                opacity: 0.6,
                cursor: 'default'
            },
        });
    if (val == "up") {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: "/idea/vote_up?id="+theid,
            success: function(){
                        $("#votewrapper").unblock();
                        }   
               });
    } else {
         $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: "/idea/vote_down?id="+theid,
            success: function(){
                        $("#votewrapper").unblock();
                        }   
               });
    }
})
```

(evry user can vote for an idea
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs. As far as I can see, Rails is catching the request before you do, so the request is probably happening, but your custom javascript just is too late.

This is because you've specified `remote: true` inside your links. That means that Rails (with `jquery_ujs`, which is automatically included) will perform this link as an AJAX request.

Leave out `remote: true` if you want to handle the request yourself; or hook into the AJAX request made by Rails.

Just an idea (by heart, so probably not right):

```
$('a[data-vote]').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
  // something
});
```